# Why did Tor Client from Browser in Windows cannot connect to Tor Network using a user-provided Tor Bridge Information

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install, obfs4

**My goal:** Establish Tor network from Tor Browser (in Windows 10) using a user-provided Tor Bridge.

**What I did so far:** Following [this Tor Wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy), I set an obfs4 Tor Bridge up in an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I found that the setup is successful. I checked from syslog and Tor Metric. The syslog showed:

> Tor[25298]: Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
>   Tor[25298]: Starting with guard context "default"
>   Tor[25298]: Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
>   Tor[25298]: Signaled readiness to systemd
>   systemd[01]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
>   Tor[25298]: Registered server transport 'obfs4' at '[::]:44815'
>   Tor[25298]: Opening Socks listener on /var/run/tor/socks
>   Tor[25298]: Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
>   Tor[25298]: Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
>   Tor[25298]: Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
>   Tor[25298]: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
>   Tor[25298]: Bootstrapped 100%: Done
>   Tor[25298]: Now checking whether ORPort ***.***.***.**:9001 is reachable... (this may take up to 20 minutes -- look for log messages indicating success)
>   Tor[25298]: Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.

The Tor metric showed the Tor Bridge has Fast, Running, V2Dir, and Valid flags so far and the Advertised Bandwidth is 59 kiB/s.

Now from a laptop machine (Windows 10), I have installed Tor Browser 8.0.2 and tried to connect Tor network using the private obfs4 bridge. I failed to do that. I have tried some troubleshoots but nothing worked. When I used built-in Tor bridges from the configuration of the Tor Browser, the connection established. Even when I used bridges after requesting BridgeDB and passing a CAPTCHA, the connection formed successfully. But when I configured the Tor Browser giving credential of my own Bridge, it didn't work.

Can you please help how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to make TCP connection to your bridge? I also found that best is to run relay/bridge  on https port, it is less likely to be blocked.

Comment: Still not. The ORPort is set to 9001 and torrc has "ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:44815" on the server side. From the client, Tor Browser, still I cannot make any connection using the information of the bridge. Are you suggesting to change ServerTransportListenAddr to some other port?

Comment: Yes set it to https port to check if you are not blocked by isp also Do you have correct bridge configuration on client side? Check  DataDir/pt_state/obfs4_bridgeline.txt

Comment: Thank you for the help. The current situation is one of the collaborators of mine can connect to Tor using the bridge. That indicates that the server-side configuration of the bridge is working properly and the port is not blocked by ISP. For some unknown reason, I can't connect to Tor from my laptop where is the Tor Browser 8.0.2 client.